Issues Configuring Nextcloud AIO with CapRover and Nginx Reverse Proxy
I'm trying to set up Nextcloud AIO (All-in-One) on my server using CapRover. The setup involves configuring a reverse proxy with Nginx to route requests to the appropriate Docker containers. Here's what I've done so far:
Following the instructions in the CapRover documentation for using a docker-compose.yml file, I added the nginx reverse proxy one clic app and set up the captain-overlay-network networks
This is my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer:
    image: nextcloud/all-in-one:20240424_101241-latest
    init: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer
    volumes:
      - nextcloud_aio_mastercontainer:/mnt/docker-aio-config
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - captain-overlay-network
    environment:
      NEXTCLOUD_DATADIR: /home/ubuntu/nextcloud-local
      APACHE_PORT: 11000
      APACHE_IP_BINDING: 127.0.0.1
      SKIP_DOMAIN_VALIDATION: true
      WATCHTOWER_DOCKER_SOCKET_PATH: '/var/run/docker.sock'

volumes:
  nextcloud_aio_mastercontainer:
    name: nextcloud_aio_mastercontainer

networks:
  captain-overlay-network:
    external: true

The reverse proxy is configured to direct requests from nextcloud.myDomain.com to https://nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer:8080 using the appropriate environment variable: UPSTREAM_HTTP_ADDRESS=https://nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer:8080
When I run the command docker compose up -d everything works perfectly and I arrive on the nextcloud page which ends with /containers and the installation ends with all the docker containers displayed in green . The web page gives me the administrator credentials and tells me to go and log in to get started.
Here's my problem:
I can't leave this configuration page. When I click on the login button I'm redirected to the same page. If I log out I get this message:

I'm not sure, but I think that once the configuration is complete, the reverse proxy should direct web requests to the nextcloud-aio-apache docker container, but I can't manage it.
UPSTREAM_HTTP_ADDRESS=https://nextcloud-aio-apache:11000
Does not work
If it helps, here's a screenshot of what docker ps returns

I know the problem seems very specific, but if anyone can tell me how the network works, that would be very helpful.
